# Separate character column by Nth character?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Given a sample df:

```
df <- structure(list(test_id = c("123-456789123", "785-525135627", 
"6545646545665456", "988898-65464654646464664", "987-656546464", "666-654564654"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to separate the above column to 2 columns:

1. Last N chars of the id (say 8)
2. The prefix left

For example given `N = 8`:

```
987-656546464 ---> split to: postfix  prefix
                             56546464 987-6
```

I have tried separate function to do this:

```
separate(df, col = test_id, into = c("prefix", "postfix"), sep = "(.{8}$)", convert = T)
```

But it doesn't give me the second part.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried `str_sub` from library `stringr`?

Comment: Try `separate(df, col = test_id, into = c("prefix", "postfix"), sep = 8, convert = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos tried it but the postfix is empty column...

Comment: @Sotos tried with sep = 8 didn't work as expected. I know for sure that the last 8 chars are unique in my large id column. But I don't know which prefix is added to these 8 last chars. That's why I want to split by last N (8) chars.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice the *last* 8 characters.

Comment: @Sotos you've helped a lot. Maybe you can explain the `"\\d(?=\\d{8,})"` regex?

Comment: @JonnyCrunch it worked:
`str_sub("3563342532362634", end = nchar("3563342532362634") - 8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `df` shown in question is NOT a data.frame so let us call it `x` instead.   Then convert it to a data frame and use `separate` with `sep = -8` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x <- df 

x %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  separate(test_id, into = c("pre", "post"), sep = -8)
```

giving:

```
               pre     post
1            123-4 56789123
2            785-5 25135627
3         65456465 45665456
4 988898-654646546 46464664
5            987-6 56546464
6            666-6 54564654
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update rough answer** df2 is df

```
library(tidyverse)
df2$text_id<-gsub("[-]", "\\1 \\2", df2$test_id)
df2$test_id
df2<-df2 %>% 
  mutate(text_id=str_remove_all(df2$text_id,"\\s"),
         text_id=substr(df2$text_id,1,5))
df2$tesxt_id<-str_replace_all(df2$text_id," ","-")
df2 %>% 
  separate(test_id,c("pre","post"),sep="\\d(?=\\d{8,})",convert = T) %>% 
  select(tesxt_id,post)
```

Result:

```
 tesxt_id     post
  <chr>       <int>
1 123-4    56789123
2 785-5    25135627
3 65456          NA
4 98889          NA
5 987-6    56546464
6 666-6    54564654
```

Try this: Rename columns as necessary. This matches any digit with atleast an 8 digit number infront. We use a lookahead(`?=`) that checks if ahead of a digit `\\d` we have a number with at least 8 digits `\\d{8,}`.

```
df %>% 
  separate(test_id,c("pre","post"),sep="\\d(?=\\d{8,})",convert = T)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: 
separate on: find a digit where you have 8 or more digits after this. Given 123456789123 it will find that number 4 is the number that followed by 8 or more digits infront. @nelsongon

Comment: Yep, it will find 4.

Comment: Ooh, why's that? The problem is we lose one digit. We lose 6 in the above example.

Comment: Try it on my sample dataset provided with the question. It's a string not a number.
I want to split on last N chars

Answer (score 1):

Without using additional package but with `sapply` and `strsplit` (obviosuly you should wrap things into functions to have a clearer syntax):

```
>t(sapply(df[,1],function(i,n){sp=unlist(strsplit(i,""));c(postfix=paste0(sp[(length(sp)-n+1):length(sp)],collapse=""),prefix=paste0(sp[1:(length(sp)-n)],collapse=""))},n=8))
                         postfix    prefix
123-456789123            "56789123" "123-4"
785-525135627            "25135627" "785-5"
6545646545665456         "45665456" "65456465"
988898-65464654646464664 "46464664" "988898-654646546"
987-656546464            "56546464" "987-6"
666-654564654            "54564654" "666-6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what solved my issue without loosing any digit.
Remember the goal was to separate the 8 characters from the end and see what is left (the prefix of the 8 last characters).
I need to know what are the unique prefixes to the last 8 characters are in my data.

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(test_id = str_sub(test_id, end = nchar(test_id) - 8))
```